# Unity takes ages to start after log in

Tags: 12.04, unity, boot-time

After I upgraded to 12.04 from 11.10,Unity has started taking too long to start.

Booting from zero to BURG takes about 3 sec,BURG to login screen takes about 5-7sec...n then login screen to unity takes more than 2 min...why so?

I've even tried stuff like disableing networking and stuff...

Comment: Pastebin `dmesg` output and current `syslog`

Comment: the dmesg output- http://paste.ubuntu.com/1025052/

Comment: Better log to focus is /var/log/Xorg.0.log

Comment: How much ram do you have on your pc and what video driver U use ?

Comment: If you want to help to solve your problem : `cat /var/log/Xorg.0.log >> xorg.txt` then `gedit xorg.txt` and pastebin the output.

Comment: Could you check the **~/.xsession-errors** file and see if that could provide us with useful data? Maybe even pastebin it?

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-session/+bug/1001138

Try moving aside the file ~/.config/compiz-1/compizconfig/config and then logging in again.

```
mv ~/.config/compiz-1/compizconfig/config ~/.config/compiz-1/compizconfig/config.backup
```

If you can login fast now, then you can put back the file and try to just delete these lines as described in the bug comments:

```
+[gnome_session]
+profile =
```

Or you can just leave it and use the freshly generated confg.

Comment: nope!!  no change whatsoever! still takes...AGES... :(

Comment: In that case try creating a new user account and logging in under that.

Answer (score 1):

Try to disable unused applications that start when you boot the system I did it and for me it worked .
Disable some startup applications

By default on Ubuntu startup applications are no longer visible, for "security reasons" for new users, those processes that are started at boot time, some may be turned off if you do not need them, speeding up the boot, for make them appear open the terminal and type:

```
cd / etc / xdg / autostart /
```

And then:

```
sudo sed - in-place 's / nodisplay = true / nodisplay = false / g' *. desktop
```

Then insert our password. Applications now open boot and disable the services that you do not need

Comment: I don't think this is a problem with startup apps, it should not take so much time to finish starting up

Answer (score 1):

Install `bootchart` and `pybootchartgui` and upload the .png file in `/var/log/bootchart`.

Anyway, it'll show you the entire procedure from system up till the complete boot. Disable time-consuming but non-required packages. Install the application bug for this.

All these packages can be installed this way: `$sudo apt-get install <package_name>`

Also run the command:

```
    `$sudo sed -i 's/NoDisplay=true/NoDisplay=false/g' /etc/xdg/autostart/*.desktop`
```

Now open 'Startup Applications' and uncheck whatever you don't wish to load during boot.

Answer (score -1):

I tried [these tips](http://www.techdrivein.com/2011/07/5-quick-tips-to-improve-ubuntu-1104.html) and they worked for me. Really improved the performance of my machine.

Hope this will help.